# Get RecordTypeId of Dynamic type

Tags: apex

I have lightning component that I want to be able to override any object edit button. I pass the recordId and objectName to the apex controller:

```
public static String getRedirect(String recordId,String objectType){
    //turn the string into an id and object name
    Id obId = Id.valueOf(recordId);
    Schema.SObjectType obtype = obId.getSObjectType();
    // ...
```

Now all I want to do is get the recordTypeId of whatever this object is. This'll work with known objects:

```
switch on objectName{
        when 'Account' {
            return getAccountRedirect(recordId);
        }
        when 'Opportunity' { ...
```

But I want to be more dynamic:

```
 String query = "Select Id,recordTypeid From"+objectType+"Where Id="+recordId; 
 sObject sob = Database.query(query);

 String rectypeid = sob.recordTypeid;
```

This doesn't work though because recordTypeId is not a field on SObject.
So I looked at [this](http://Account%20acc%20=%20[Select%20Id,recordtype.developername,%20Address_verification__c%20From%20Account%20Where%20Id=:recordId];) which kinda helped but I still can't find a way to dynamically get an objects record type.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the get method, assuming the object has a record type available:

```
if(obType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('recordtypeid')) {
  SObject record = Database.query('SELECT RecordTypeId FROM '+obType+' WHERE Id = \''+recordId+'\'');
  Id recordTypeId = (Id)record.get('RecordTypeId');
  // ...
}
```

Comment: sweeet thanks ! jsut what I was lookin for

Comment: Hi, is there a way where we dont need to use the apex class and still can make the 'recordtypeid' as dynamic in lightning controller.

Comment: @9codie05 In Aura or LWC? You might just want to ask a new question so we can get all the pertinent details. I'd be glad to take a look at it for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox In Aura and I have asked a question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268733/dynamic-recordtypeid-in-lightning-controller-system-event
Thanks for your comment.